# Using ads - Google Play Service vs. Android SDK

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I'd like to implement banner-ads in my new app and stumbled across two possibilitys of doing this.

The first one is using the Android SDK: `com.google.ads.*`
The second one is using Google Play Services: `com.google.android.gms.ads.*`

I googled a lot and read the documentation but I found no resources which state the differences between both solutions.

What is the difference between both and which one is the best if I simply want to add banner-ads in my app?

Comment: "i googled a lot" ... yeah sure  ... https://www.google.com/?q=google+admob+vs+play+adds#q=google+admob+vs+play+adds first link and from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android  you can read: `Deprecated. On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK by then.`

Comment: Oh, I googled a lot but I must have missed this. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Selvin** did not post his comment as an answer I'll answer this question by myself:

Use the Google Play Services `com.google.android.gms.ads.*`

Don't use the Android SDK for Ads because it is deprecated:

> Deprecated. On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or
>   updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1
>   or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play version of the Mobile
>   Ads SDK by then.

[Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android)

Answer (score 0):

Direct to the point,
The main difference is that if you use Google Play Services one then you will use Google play service APIs. If you use other modules of Google Play like maps, location, gcm, play games then you can use `com.google.android.gms.ads.*` but if you don't use other Services then use `com.google.ads.*`

Their behavior is same...